# Storing data like a "Title" other information inside a placed 3D object in AR using ARKit

Tags: swift, arkit

Is it possible to create a new stationary object (like a circle or a square) while in ARKit that can contain information inputted by the user through being typed on the keyboard and then essentially stored in the "augmented reality world".

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you may be thinking about this the wrong way around. If you have some data you're representing in AR, you should be representing that data in your *data model* and *representing* it in the AR world.

When I say *data model* here I mean the conceptual things you mean to represent in AR, not the *3D model objects* you'll construct and/or manipulate in AR. You'll have some `Thing` model object and feed them to ARKit for representation via some controller-layer object that holds and manages the collection of `Thing`s.

Example: You have a list of dog breeds and want to project an example of each breed in AR by showing a 3D model of the dog of the given breed and a title under it. You'd represent your list in your app's *model* (maybe by creating a `Breed` struct that has a name and other details, and storing an array/collection of `Breed` for each breed you want to show). You'd then use this collection of breeds to drive ARKit by showing the appropriate 3D model for the selected breed, with an attached text node to display the `Breed.name` property, or any other properties.

There are fancier ways of modeling the above example but that's quite a broad topic and very specific to your application.